# How to change the text of a button with css, if it has several elements inside

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this button that the only way to modify it is with an added css, since it is on a wordpress site and I cannot edit the button code

How can I change the text of **"Me gustas"** using only css, since it has several elements inside I can not only using content

```
<span class="sl-count">
    <span class="recommend-title">Recommend</span>
    <span class="count-num">0</span> 
    Me gustas
</span>
```

Comment: Are you using a child theme?

Comment: yes i am using a child theme

Comment: I would therefore consider altering the text actually in the DOM so it is accessible. E.g by changing single.php or other relevant code or if that is a step too far running some JS at load time to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
.sl-count {
    font-size: 0; // hide the text inside the button
}

.sl-count span {
  
   font-size: 16px; // we do want to show the spans
}

// insert text using an :after element and give it font-size to make it visible.
.sl-count:after {
  
   content: "Something else.";
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

This is not a good solution tho, because the HTML still reads the old text, so SEO/Accessibility is not going to read the text coming from the CSS.